# Oracle RMAN Full Database Recovery

Tags: oracle, rman

I want to restore a full database backup of a database in noarchivelog, but not the last backup. How can I select the full backup to restore?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a proper backup, you can specify the point in time of the restore as follows:

```
 RUN
 { 
     SET UNTIL SCN 1000;    
     # Alternatives:
     # SET UNTIL TIME 'Nov 15 2004 09:00:00';
     # SET UNTIL SEQUENCE 9923;  
     RESTORE DATABASE;
     RECOVER DATABASE;
  }
```

Look into Oracle documentation at http://tahiti.oracle.com for your specific Oracle version for more details.

IC.

Comment: In NOARCHIVELOG mode you can't do a point in time recovery - where are the archive logs to get you there?